# Mac OS X PPTP VPN issue ping: sendto: No buffer space available

Tags: mac-osx, vpn, pptp, pptp-client

The VPN connects successfully but after some time the connection is unusable (VPN is used as primary gateway). Ping would reveal:

ping: sendto: No buffer space available

This looks like the same issue discussed here: http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=12514921#12514921

Hopefully you might have a workaround.

I have Mac OS X 10.6.4

Comment: I have this issue too. Unfortunately the vpn is a commercial vpn so I can't try the suggestions listed below (I don't know of any hosts on the network).

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that sending constant pings to a host on the VPN will help overcome this exact issue.

Find an ip address of a computer on the network you know will be happy to take a pings all day (a web server maybe?).
Open a terminal by going into spotlight (command+space) and typing 'Terminal'.
In the window that appears type (without quotes)

```
ping "ip-address-here"
```

so for example:

```
ping 192.168.0.123
```

Then just let it ping for as long as you need to keep your session open. I've found that leaving it all day has no negative affects.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the issue is most likely a UDP session timeout in my router (decreased from 120 to 90). And I have to send constant pings to a remote node (in the VPN remote network).